# Unit test in Spring boot using Mockito

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit4

While executing Juint4 test. it shows null pointer exception. while using save method in unit test it returns null. Here i am using Mockito Juint4 Testing to mock the method.  someone help me out with this.

```
**Service Method.**


    public Result save(Map inputParams){

        Result result = new Result();

        logger.info("::::::::::::::: save ::::::::::::::::"+inputParams);
        try{
            String name = inputParams.get("name").toString();
            String type = inputParams.get("type").toString();

            CoreIndustry coreIndustry = coreIndustryDao.findByName(name);
            if(coreIndustry != null){
                result.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FOUND.value());
                result.setMessage(Messages.NAME_EXIST_MESSAGE);
                result.setSuccess(false);
            }else{
                CoreIndustry coreIndustryNew = new CoreIndustry();
                coreIndustryNew.setName(name);
                coreIndustryNew.setType(type);
                coreIndustryNew.setInfo(new Gson().toJson(inputParams.get("info")));
                System.out.println("CoreIndustry Info is :............:.............:..............:"+coreIndustryNew.getInfo());
                CoreIndustry coreIndustryData = coreIndustryDao.save(coreIndustryNew);
                System.out.println("Saved Data Is.............::::::::::::::::::::................ "+coreIndustryData.getName()+"  "+coreIndustryData.getType()+"    "+coreIndustryData.getType());
                result.setData(coreIndustryData);
                result.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());
                result.setMessage(Messages.CREATE_MESSAGE);
                result.setSuccess(true);
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            logger.error("::::::::::::::: Exception ::::::::::::::::"+e.getMessage());

            result.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
            result.setSuccess(false);
            result.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        }

        return result;

    }

    **Controller**   


    @PostMapping(path = "/industry/save")
            public Result save(@RequestBody  Map<String, Object> stringToParse)  {
                logger.debug("save---------------"+stringToParse);
                Result result = industryService.save(stringToParse);
                return result;
            }


**Unit Test**


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class IndustryServiceTest {

    @MockBean
    private CoreIndustryDao coreIndustryDao;


    private IndustryService industryService;


    @Test
    public void getAll() {

        System.out.println(":::::::  Inside of GetAll Method of Controller.");
       // when(coreIndustryDao.findAll()).thenReturn(Stream.of(
         //       new CoreIndustry("Dilip","Brik","Brik Industry"))
           //     .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        //assertEquals(1,industryService.getAll().setData());
    }

    @Test
    public void save() {

        ObjectMapper oMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        CoreIndustry coreIndustry = new CoreIndustry();
        coreIndustry.setId(2L);
        coreIndustry.setName("Dilip");
        coreIndustry.setType("Business");
        HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap();
        map.put("name","Retail");
        map.put("type","Development");
        coreIndustry.setInfo(new Gson().toJson(map));

        when(coreIndustryDao.save(any(CoreIndustry.class))).thenReturn(new CoreIndustry());

        Map<String, Object> actualValues = oMapper.convertValue(coreIndustry,Map.class);


        System.out.println("CoreIndustry Filed values are........ : "+coreIndustry.getName()+"    "+coreIndustry.getInfo());
        Result created = industryService.save(actualValues);
        CoreIndustry coreIndustryValue = (CoreIndustry) created.getData();

        Map<String, Object> expectedValues = oMapper.convertValue(coreIndustryValue, Map.class);

        System.out.println(" Getting Saved data from CoreIndustry........"+expectedValues);

        System.out.println(" Getting Saved data from CoreIndustry........"+coreIndustryValue.getName());
        assertThat(actualValues).isSameAs(expectedValues);



    }
```

I am new in this Spring boot Technology.

[After Running the source code for save method.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXE5O.png)
[After Debugging my source code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbazE.png).

> It will be great please to help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Did you mocked your coreIndustryDao e.g @Mock CoreIndustryDao coreIndustryDao;?

Comment: Would you please provide stack trace.. which line is throwing npe... most probably Mocking didn't happen as it should for CoreindustryDao

Comment: Instead of adding images containing your stacktrace, please add them as text. Also point out which line the exception comes from and how the classes `IndustryService` and `CoreIndustryDao` are related.